# Truck cab- cargo box interface plywood finishing

Tags: plywood, finishing

Using 3/4" yellow pine, ~7layer, sanded plywood.
The finished project needs to appear semi-gloss white.
Priority: water-resistant.
Time in service: 5 years min.

1. From my research I should seal the edge with epoxy or body filler.
2. Polyurethane or latex (water or oil) overall, min. 3 coats sanding between.
   Correct?
   Comments welcome.

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately your question isn't very clear. We're not a discussion forum, so you need to revise to be more specific. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What does "interface" mean in this context?

Comment: You want a white bed liner made out of wood that will last 5 years when coated? It depends if anything will ever be put on the wood. More info is needed and the type of use. Epoxy will last that long and look great for 5 years if nothing heavy enough to deform the wood and make the epoxy paint crack, but if it cracks it’s not so great in 5 years.